# Vue.js parent child communication using props

Tags: vue.js

I have the setup below using vue2.0.  The method something() is called which updates 'place' on the parent.  I want the child to watch for changes to place, and when it updates to react accordingly.  However, the watch method in the child is never called.  Any idea what's wrong here please?

Thanks,

```
// parent
import home from './components/home.vue'

var App = window.App = new Vue({
data: {
  place: '',
},
methods: {
  something: function(event) {
    this.place = 'some new place'
  })
},
components: {
  'home': home,
}
}).$mount('#app')

// child ('./components/home.vue')
export default {
  props: ['place'],
  // need to react here when place changes
  watch: {
    place: function (val, oldVal) {
      console.log('new: %s, old: %s', val, oldVal)
    },
}
```

Comment: have you tried that `<home :place="place"></home>`

Comment: i don't use home as a component like that.

Comment: can you provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass the place prop to the component?

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var home = {
  props: ['place'],
  template: '<div>home: {{ place }}</div>',
  watch: {
    place: function (val, oldVal) {
      console.log('new: %s, old: %s', val, oldVal)
    }
  }
};

var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'home': home
  },
  data: {
    place: 'somewhere'
  },
  methods: {
    something: function(event) {
      this.place = 'some new place'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="something">set place</button>
  <p>app: {{ place }}</p>
  <home :place="place"></home>
</div>
```